# Update a react-native applications to load the JavaScript bundle from a server running on a non-standard (8081) port

Tags: react-native

I'm running react-native on a corporate Macboook which runs McAfee on port 8081.. this process is un-killable (keeps popping up after kill -9)

so the only way i could run the react-native bundle server is by specifying a different port this way:
`react-native start --port=8088`

now the official docs (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html) say:

```
You will also need to update your applications to load the JavaScript bundle from the new port. Open the in-app Developer menu, then go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device and replace 8081 with your port of choice.
```

Question is:
How can i start the [Developer menu](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#accessing-the-in-app-developer-menu) if i am not able to load the app in the simulator simulator?
(react-native --run-ios) keep crashing because it tries to access 8081

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to update port please check (this answer)(https://stackoverflow.com/a/54418960/3932166)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had to change:
in **RCTBundleURLProvider.m**

`const NSUInteger kRCTBundleURLProviderDefaultPort = 8081;`

 to 
`const NSUInteger kRCTBundleURLProviderDefaultPort = 8088;`

And in **RCTWebSocketExecutor.m** 
`port = [[[_bridge bundleURL] port] integerValue] ?: 8081;`

 to 
`port = [[[_bridge bundleURL] port] integerValue] ?: 8088;`

And lastly: 
open the iOS project in Xcode, in the project navigator > Libraries > React.xcodeproj > Build Phases, change all occurrences of 8081 to 8088.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I think this is an error in React Native's documentation.

If you have your bundler already running in port 8088 you can also modify the default port for React Native in React Native's code. This can be done in RCTBundleURLProvider:

Go to your XCode explorer and search for this file

[image: Xcode Explorer]

You should change
`const NSUInteger kRCTBundleURLProviderDefaultPort = 8081;`
for
`const NSUInteger kRCTBundleURLProviderDefaultPort = 8088;`

And everything should work now on port 8088

Of course this is a patch, one should never modify React Native's code but it can be used as a workaround until this gets fixed in future versions

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to kill your app by `kill -9` then just run `pkill node` command to kill all your running port.