# Is there an easy way to change the default port when i type in react-native run-android?

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

My steps to change the default port:

1. react-native start --port 9999.
2. react-native run-android.
3. change the port in the app.

Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

You can also change permanent the port with change default server in react native node modules `your_app\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\server\server.js` and change the port 8081 to 9999 like this :

```
....
module.exports = {
 name: 'start',
 func: server,
 description: 'starts the webserver',
 options: [{
   command: '--port [number]',
   default: 8081,  //change to 9999
   parse: (val: string) => Number(val),
 },
 ....
```

I hope this answer can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your port of your react-native project by below commands. just save below code in file can be named as `update-port` and run this file by `/file/path/update-port`at your react-native project level (Where you run `npm start` or `yarn start` then no need to change anything just run `yarn start` and your code automatically run on `8082`.

**Note:-**

1. **You can directly run below command at project level.**
2. **you can also update port number replace `8082` with your port number.**
3. **For Android you need to set port in `dav setting/Debug Server host & port for device` then set port like `127.1.0.0:8082`** (first your ip and then use your port).
4. **When ever your update your node-module the default port will automatically change then please re-run `update-port` file.**

```
#!/bin/bash


sed -i '' 's/8081/8082/g' ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/server.js
sed -i '' 's/8081/8082/g' ./node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBridgeDelegate.h
sed -i '' 's/8081/8082/g' ./node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTDefines.h
sed -i '' 's/8081/8082/g' ./node_modules/react-native/React/DevSupport/RCTInspectorDevServerHelper.mm
sed -i '' 's/8081/8082/g' ./node_modules/react-native/React/React.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
sed -i '' 's/8081/8082/g' ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js
sed -i '' 's/8081/8082/g' ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/util/isPackagerRunning.js
sed -i '' 's/8081/8082/g' ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js
sed -i '' 's/8081/8082/g' ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTTest/RCTTestRunner.m
```